# How to show different type of custom messages at input in form validation with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have built a from and trying to implement validation process with angularjs. At my source code, you will see I have three input fields:

1. Email
2. Password
3. Confirm Password

At Email, I can show a **'Required message'** and a **'Custom Message'** by doing this:

```
 <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" ng-model="email" required>
<p ng-show="createLogin.inputEmail.$error.required">This field is required</p>
<p ng-show="createLogin.inputEmail.$error.email">Enter a valid email<p>
```

This is completely fine. But, following the same procedure at other two input fields(Password & Confirm Password), I can't show the **'Custom Messages'**! Only **'Required Messages'** are shown. How can I fix this? This is the code which I have used for password:

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="createPassword" name="createPassword" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password" password-validate required>
<div ng-show="createLogin.createPassword.$error.required"><p>This field is required</p></div>
<div ng-show="createLogin.createPassword.$error.password">
     <p>Custom Messages:</p>
 </div>
```

And for Confirm Password:

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" placeholder="Password" ng-model="verifyPass" required data-password-verify="password">
<p ng-show="createLogin.confirmPassword.$error.required">This field is required</p>
<p ng-show="createLogin.confirmPassword.$error.verifyPass">Password don't match<p>
```

So, how can I show the **Custom Messages** for `Password` and `Confirm Password` filed too like `Email` filed?

[Here is my Plunker work](http://plnkr.co/edit/I7XkqDK64HGeFFjDB3uS?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your custom directive set validation key to `pwd` (`ctrl.$setValidity('pwd', true)`) you need to use it in HTML in expressions like:

```
<div ng-show="createLogin.createPassword.$error.pwd">
    <p>Password must meet the following requirements:</p>
    <ul>
        <li ng-class="pwdHasLetter">At least <strong>one letter</strong></li>
        <li ng-class="pwdHasNumber">At least <strong>one number</strong></li>
        <li ng-class="pwdValidLength">Be at least <strong>8 characters</strong></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The same issue with password verification field, key should be `passwordVerify`:

```
<p ng-show="createLogin.confirmPassword.$error.passwordVerify">Password don't match</p>
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/zMbCxcdkYggOdvXYkMX1?p=preview

Comment: ok, thanks. Also for Password Confirmation filed what I need to add at HTML?

Comment: the same with password validation it should be `<p ng-show="createLogin.confirmPassword.$error.passwordVerify">Password don't match</p>`

Comment: Ops, I should understand that I've to add 'passwordVerify' as I've used ctrl.$setValidity("passwordVerify", true); Thanks again!

Comment: yes, `$setValidity` sets corresponding key to `$error` object.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the below link

http://plnkr.co/edit/iSFp3n4PSDTM6pRofXc2

Following is the directive for matching passwords.

Directive

```
app.directive('pwdMatch', function () {
 return {
     require: 'ngModel',
     restrict: 'A',
     scope: {
         pwdMatch: '='
     },
     link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
         scope.$watch(function () {
             var modelValue = ctrl.$modelValue || ctrl.$$invalidModelValue;
             return (ctrl.$pristine && angular.isUndefined(modelValue)) || scope.pwdMatch === modelValue;
         }, function (currentValue) {
             ctrl.$setValidity('pwdMatch', currentValue);
         });
     }
 };
})
```

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="password" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Password</label>

      <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter password"
                       ng-model="user.password" name="password" required="true"
                       ng-pattern="/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Za-z])[a-zA-Z0-9~!@#$%^&*]{6,15}$/">
          <span ng-show="signUpForm.password.$dirty && signUpForm.password.$error.required">
          <small class="text-danger">Please enter a password.</small>
          </span>
          <span ng-show="signUpForm.password.$dirty && !signUpForm.password.$error.required && signUpForm.password.$error.pattern">
            <small class="text-danger">Password should have 6 to 15 characters with alphabets and digits</small>
         </span>

      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="confirmPassword" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>

    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirmPassword" id="confirmPassword"
                       placeholder="Confirm password" ng-model="user.confirmPassword" required="true"
                       data-pwd-match="user.password">
    <span ng-show="signUpForm.confirmPassword.$dirty && (signUpForm.confirmPassword.$error.required || signUpForm.confirmPassword.$error.pwdMatch)">
        <small class="text-danger">Passwords do not match.</small>
    </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.